# Magento 2 - detect orders that are placed via REST API

Tags: magento2, event-observer

Is there a way to detect orders that are placed via API? I want to add to those orders a different order number prefix.

I have already created an observer that is changing the prefix based on payment method of the order and I want to extend it to change the prefix based on order placed on web or API.

Event for observer now is **sales_order_place_after**

I have an observer that is doing that and I want to fix it in observer but what I need to take into consideration are the prefix for:

- web orders paid by card
- web orders with bank transfer
- API orders paid by card
- API orders with bank transfer

Basically I need 4 types of prefix.

Because of this, the functionality that I need now is a way to detect when an order comes from API vs orders that comes from web

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

To identify the order placed on website or via API, you can check the HTTP Origin of the request (HTTP_ORIGIN). If the order placing on the website, the HTTP Origin will return the website base URL, otherwise, it will return an empty string.

Implementation of the Observer class:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ChangeOrderPrefix implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var RequestInterface
     */
    private $request;

    public function __construct(RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * Change the order prefix based on ...
     *
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        // If HTTP_ORIGIN has value that means the order placed on website
        if ($this->request->getServer('HTTP_ORIGIN')) {
            // Code for the order placed on website
        } else {
            // Code for the order placed via API
        }
        // Your customize code goes here

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think their is no way to check if order was placed via API or browser by using Magento Events **sales_order_place_after** because by Default on browser the javascript also place order via API **payment-information**

- In this case i think you has to implement a javascript code which adding an additional information to payment-info on the browser which this information allow you tracking which order was placed on Browser.

**A hit for you**: Adding a hook to **place-order-hooks.js** which allow you update the payload before submit to server.